# How can I perform some stuff every 60 seconds in Python Flask, and then update all user pages?

Tags: python, html, flask, celery, python-asyncio

I am currently working on an turn-based online webgame. I want every player to be able to choose a move, and every 60 seconds the chosen moves of all players should get performed simultaneously (if no move is chosen, a default move gets performed). I am planning to save the chosen move in a SQL database. The only problem is, I have no idea, how to perform something each 60 seconds.

I have tried to use asyncio and have read that Celery could help me, but I didn't really understood how to achieve exactly the result I need. As I understood, the guides were helping only to use the stuff inside the flask app, but not simultaneously with the flask app

Comment: [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use threading:

```
import threading
import time

def perform_task():
    print("Performing task")

def schedule_task():
    while True:
        perform_task()
        time.sleep(60)

thread = threading.Thread(target=schedule_task)
thread.start()
```

Comment: That's nice and it actually works rn (thank you very much), but do you have an idea how I could also make the page of every user to reload as part of the perform_task()? Otherwise I should probably build a simultaneous timer into each page, by using time.time() to synchronize